# Why does .end() point to the past-the-end element and not to .back()?

Tags: algorithm, c++11

I lately had some trouble with `.lower_bound()` until i found out that it returns an iterator to the past-the-end element if no value fits the argument. The same for `.end()`, which points to the past-the-end entry.

What's the use of the past-the-end element and why does it not just points to the very last element of the vector? E.g. to the element that `.back()` returns?

Comment: Because `back()` can be a valid element, so it cannot mean "no element found"? The past-the-end element allows using simple half-open-on-right ranges of the form [first, one-past-last). Those conceptually can easily express empty sets: [x, x) is an empty set/range.

Comment: Two words: empty sequence.

Comment: Try to divide a range into two subranges. [a, b) = [a, c) + [c, b). Notice identical types (half-open). Try to do that with [a, b]. It doesn't work.